# Table Adapter Bindings Not Updating

Tags: c#, oracle, textbox, tableadapter

I am using C# with Visual Studio 2010, using Bindings and an Oracle Datasource.

My block of code is as follows

```
//This loads the information into the textbox
        try
        {
            this.invoicePrimariesTableAdapter.FillByInvoiceID(this.nISSANDataset.InvoicePrimaries);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        //This changes the contents of the textbox
        int invoiceID = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoiceNum.Text);
        invoiceID += 1;
        txtInvoiceNum.Text = Convert.ToString(invoiceID);
        //This tries to update the Database, but fails
        try
        {

            this.Validate();
            this.invoicePrimariesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.invoicePrimariesTableAdapter.Update(this.nISSANDataset.InvoicePrimaries);                
            MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi" + ex);
        }
```

I am looking to increment the value in the database by 1 each time the form loads. This was what I though of, but if there's a better way, or a way to make this work, I would be very happy.

Comment: The better way would be to change the DataRow instead of the UI. The Values in the UI should only be changed via the UI and the Binding. In code change the data directly in the model.

Comment: The issue has been fixed on my end. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to have been all my fault. I forgot that I added another column to the database, but didn't update my datasource in my C# Project. It went to update a 2 column table and instead found a 3 column table and broke.